# How to arrange items in a list box by using radio button REPOST

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok, so i want to be able to display all the information in the list box when the radio button 'all' is clicked. I also want to be able to display the players "only" when the 'players' radio button is clicked, the same for manager's also. Any help? Thanks!

```
class Create 
{ 
    public enum Job { Player, Manager } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int Age { get; set; } 
    public Job Porm { get; set; } 

    public Create(string name, int age, Job porm) 
    { 
        Name = name; Age = age; Porm = porm; 
    } 

    public override string ToString() 
    { 
        return string.Format("Name: {0} - Age {1} - {2}", Name, Age, Porm); 
    } 
}
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{ 
    public MainWindow() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
        ObservableCollection<Create> playersAndManagers; 
        playersAndManagers = new ObservableCollection<Create>();
        Create newPlayer1 = new Create("John Terry", 27, Create.Job.Player);
        Create newManager1 = new Create("jose mourinho", 51, Create.Job.Manager);
        Create newPlayer2 = new Create("Wayne Rooney", 23, Create.Job.Player);
        Create newPlayer3 = new Create("David Beckham", 37, Create.Job.Player);
        Create newManager2 = new Create("David Moyes", 55, Create.Job.Manager);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newPlayer1);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newManager1);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newPlayer2);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newPlayer3);
        playersAndManagers.Add(newManager2);
        lbxInfo.ItemsSource = playersAndManagers;
    } 
}
```

---

```
<Window x:Class="example1.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"> 
<Grid> 
<ListBox x:Name="lbxInfo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="207" Margin="66,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="368"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rbtnAll" Content="All" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
<RadioButton x:Name="rbtnPlayers" Content="Players" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rbtnManagers" Content="Managers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="352,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/> 
</Grid> 
</Window>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

observable collections are quite tricky, they are missing all the fancy features of a normal `List<T>`. I would suggest you to have a `List` with all the data and a second collection with the data you want to display.

To show all data you can simply say

```
lbxInfo.ItemsSource = playersAndManagers;
```

when you want to show only managers:

```
lbxInfo.ItemsSource = playersAndManagers.Where(m => m.Porm == Job.Manager)
```

and for showing only the players:

```
lbxInfo.ItemsSource = playersAndManagers.Where(p => p.Porm == Job.Player)
```

This however wouldn't update the displayed list, if the `playersAndManagers`-List changes in your application. If you want to modify the list in the application and keep the `ListBox` updated it would be the easiest to create a custom list which would have a property, which can return an `ObservableCollection` and will keep that one updated.